# Tensorflow C++ API: How to iterate Tensor with Dimesion=3?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensor

I have a tensor with shape(2,2,3) from the input. And I can get the shape of this tensor by `.shape()` which can be used to help iteration. But I fail to iterate it which may caused by the wrong conversion to matrix while matrix's dimession always 2  The code showes as below:

```
const Tensor& input = context->input(0); // get the input
DCHECK_EQ(input.dims(), 3); //check the dimission==3
const TensorShape& input_shape = input.shape(); //get the shape of the tensor
auto input_tensor = input.matrix<float>();//wrong conversion
for(int i=0; i<input_shape.dim_size(0); i++)
{
  for(int j=0; j<input_shape.dim_size(1); j++)
  {
    for(int k=0; k<input_shape.dim_size(2); k++)
      {
        count<<input_tensor(i,j,k);//wrong code
      }
  }
}
```

So, I want to know the way to iterate this tensor. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's suprised that I get the answer when I compare the matrix api and the tensor api in [Tensorflow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor.html#classtensorflow_1_1_tensor_1aacce92855f6b83eea728203de8016c78). And find the usage:

```
const Tensor& input = context->input(0); // get the input
DCHECK_EQ(input.dims(), 3); //check the dimission==3
const TensorShape& input_shape = input.shape(); //get the shape of the tensor
auto input_tensor = input.tensor<float, 3>();//true conversion
for(int i=0; i<input_shape.dim_size(0); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<input_shape.dim_size(1); j++)
    {
        for(int k=0; k<input_shape.dim_size(2); k++)
        {
           count<<input_tensor(i,j,k);//right one
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe in the before I miss the NDImission paramter.

Comment: where is the difference between this code and the code in your question?

Comment: Thank you! I copy the before code. The different should be the input_tensor's initialization follow the api "TTypes< T, NDIMS >::Tensor tensor()". and the lastest one is the 2-D tensor's initialization  follow the api " TTypes< T >::Matrix matrix()".

Comment: Yes, the TTypes<T, 3> is the right way to iterate over a 3 tensor. You can also always use .flat()(n)